# How to stack items on top of each other in a flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Test page: http://vintageamericanpottery.com/3test.html

This should be really simple, but I can't get  `<div class="welcome"></div>`  to stack on top of  `<div class="header"></div>`.
I think it's because they are both inside a flex container, but there has to be a way to make divs stack on top of each other while still in this container.

I've tried adding `display: block`, `flex-direction: column`, and `clear: both`, but it doesn't keep the elements from displaying inline.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 4%;
  padding-right: 4%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.welcome {
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #5A5A5A;
  flex-direction: column!important;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="welcome" style="/* clear:both */">Welcome to Happy Heidi's </div>
  <div class="header" style="clear:both">
    <h1>Vintage Fiesta Pottery for Sale</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can I not put anything else inside this container and have it simply stack? I want two divs at the top of this container to stack, but they just stay inline no matter what I do.

Comment: Please post the minimal amount of code here that demonstrates the problem instead of asking us to visit an unknown site and view its source to find the issue.

Comment: Is there a secret to posting code? The forum deletes my tags.
<div class="container">
<div class="welcome" style="clear:both">xxx </div>
<div class="header" style="clear:both"><h1>xxx</h1></div>  .... everything inside the container is working correctly, but these two divs I just want on top of themselves, left aligned at the top of the page, so i'd have container>welcome<br>header<br>container content...</container>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `.container` has **also** `display: flex`.

Therefore **wrap** `.welcome` and `.header` in **one** `<div></div>`

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="welcome">Welcome to Happy Heidi's</div>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Vintage Fiesta Pottery for Sale</h1></div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```